# Accessing Images outside of meteor project

Tags: file-upload, meteor

I have two meteor projects on one server. On the first one the user uploads images to a folder outside of the meteor project using https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads. Now I need a way to access these images from the second meteor project.

How would I go about accessing images/files outside of the meteor project's public folder.

Thank you,
Klai

Comment: Have you tried creating a soft link in the public folder of the second project to the external folder?

Comment: any solutions that you received?

Comment: @AnkurSoni In the end I had the images uploaded to a public directory on the server. That way the images were accessible by anything.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did lol